# Passing a particular selected item index from spinner causes app to crash, but works fine with other selected item indexes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, authentication, android-sqlite

My app **crashes** when a value called "Teacher" is selected from my spinner, passed through my method called `getDatabasePassword()` and login button is pressed.

BUT it **works fine** when a value called "Student" is selected from my spinner, passed through the same method called `getDatabasePassword()` and login button is pressed.

Details below:

I created 2 SQLite database tables each with the following columns

> TEACHER
>
> - teacherId (integer primary key NOT NULL)
> - username (text NOT NULL)
> - password (text NOT NULL)
>
> STUDENT
>
> - studentId (integer primary key NOT NULL)
> - username (text NOT NULL)
> - password (text NOT NULL)

And each of these have their own Java classes with the same named variables and appropriate getters/setters

In my Login Activity I have set an onClick method to my Login button as follows:

```
public view onClickLogin(View view){

   if (view.getId() == R.id.btnLogin){

       EditText usernameView = findViewById(R.id.usernameView);
       EditText passwordView = findViewById(R.id.passwordView); 
       Spinner spinnerView = findViewById(R.id.spinnerView);  //Spinner that contains two items: "Teacher" and "Student"
       Button loginView = findViewById(R.id.loginView);

       String username = usernameView.getText().toString();
       String password = passwordView.getText().toString();
       String position = spinnerView.getSelectedItem().toString();

       String password_db = databaseHelper.getDatabasePassword(username, position);

       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Activity_login.this, "username: " + username + ", password:  " + password + ", position: " + position;
       toast.show();
   }
}
```

And I have narrowed down the line of code from above that causes my app to crash when "Teacher" is selected in my spinner:

```
String password_db = databaseHelper.getDatabasePassword(username, position);
```

That method is in my Database Helper class:

```
public String getDatabasePassword(String username, String position){
   String table = "";
   String a, b;
   b = "Person not found."

   if (position.equals("Student"))
      table = "STUDENT";
   else if (position.equals("Teacher"))
      table = "TEACHER";

   db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   String query = "SELECT username, password FROM " + table;
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

   if (cursor.moveToFirst())
   {
      do {
         a = cursor.getString(0);
         if (a.equals(username)){
            b = cursor.getString(1);
            break;
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   return b;
   }
}
```

where `db` is `SQLiteDatabase db;`

I've already made sure that all my CREATE and INSERT queries and all other methods are working as intended and I've triple checked my spelling.  All my XML layouts and string values are spelled correctly as well.

As mentioned before, I've managed to narrow my problem down to this one function and I'm not sure why my app **crashes** when "Teacher" is selected then Login button is pressed but when "Student" is selected then Login button is pressed my app works just **fine**.

EDIT:  After checking my LogCat, I had the "No such table exist" error.  I had to uninstall and reinstall my APK build.

Comment: show the logcat error

Comment: post logcat error

Comment: post logcat error and never save passwords in clear text.

Comment: You should check particular selected item index value. Is it int integer? if it is integer than please sent your logcat.

Comment: Oh!  I just checked my LogCat and I was getting the classic "No such table" error.  I had to uninstall the APK then reinstall it.  But how can I do that in code without having to manually uninstall and reinstall the APK everytime the database upgrades / gets more tables than previous version?

Comment: @5120bee you could utilise the SQLiteOpenHelper's `onUpgrade` method as one way (it gets called when the Database version is increased).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make any change in DB like created new table or add/edit any field/column in table,
either you have to uninstall and install your app again,
or you change DB version and in onUpgrade method just delete your all table and run onCreate method again,
Thanks